# Reading a file where there is an unknown number of integers separated by spaces between curly brackets per line in C

Tags: c, readfile

I've seen this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278655/reading-in-an-unknown-number-of-integers-separated-by-spaces-into-one-vector-per), but this one doesn't work for my situation.

My situation is below:

```
1 { 87 36 135 }
2 { 100 156 167 43 92 174 149 21 }
3 { 144 7 58 149 127 189 5 54 57 }
4 { 128 61 30 4 165 72 117 }
5 { 158 104 196 156 151 162 198 }
6 { 87 98 14 }
```

My goal is to put these integers between curly brackets into a 2D array. Then, I can manipulate them.

I also tried it in the C version. My idea is to go to the left curly bracket to save the number and go to the next line when it meets the right curly bracket.

However, my idea doesn't work for the above situation because the integers my two or three characters.

```
char str1;
int count = 1;
int no;
char c;
FILE *filepointer;
// filepointer = fopen("~", "r");
filepointer = fopen(argv[1], "r");
printf("\n The content of the file %s is  :\n", argv[1]);
c = fgetc(filepointer);

while (c != EOF)
{
    if(c == '{'){
        int adj = 1;// may be careful
        while (c != '}')
        {
            while (isspace(c = fgetc(filepointer)))
                ;
            if(c == '}')
                break;
            int returnNumber = 0;
            returnNumber = returnNumber * 10 + (c - '0');
            nets[count][adj] = returnNumber;
            adj++;
        }
        count++;
    }
    
    // printf("%c", c);
    c = fgetc(filepointer);
}
no = count;
printf("\n\n");
fclose(filepointer);
for (int i = 1; i < no;i++){
    for (int j = 1; j < MAX_ADJCENT_SIZE;j++){
        printf("%d ", nets[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

What can I try next?

Comment: You are resetting `returnNumber` to zero on every iteration.

Comment: Please post the *complete* code. [btw: you fail to reset returnNumber and adj at the correct places]

Comment: You could simply use `scanf("%d"...)`.  It will return zero when you hit the `}`, which you can then consume and check.  The danger is that `%d` is subject to undefined behavior if the input contains long strings of digits, but the method you are using is subject to the same problem.  It's probably easiest to simply avoid it with a width modifier on the conversion specifier.

Comment: I post the almost entire code except int main and include

Comment: OT: regarding: `c = fgetc(filepointer);` and `char c;   the function `fgetc()` returns a `int` not a `char` and (depending on your system implementation) a `char` will not be recognized as EOF

Answer (score 0):

You could read all characters that are digits before saving the number and moving on to the next:

```
int returnNumber = 0;

if (isdigit(c)) {
    do {
        returnNumber = returnNumber * 10 + (c - '0');
        c = fgetc(filepointer));
    } while (isdigit(c));

    nets[count][adj] = returnNumber;
    adj++;
}
```

Comment: This idea works for me!
Thank you very much for your help, it is very important to me!

Comment: Instead of `c >= '0' && c <= '9'`, you could use `isdigit(c)`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thank you for your suggestion! Make code simple!  I also saw this function from other codes.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes, updated code to use `isdigit()` instead.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jia-XingZhou Thank you!  If you feel this answers your question, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @mmixLinus I don't have enough reputation. (sad) If I can, I will.